# Copying a ID3D11Texture2D created by one device without the D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_SHARED flag to another device

Tags: directx11

I'm writing a native plugin for Unity that is responsible for presenting the rendered Unity scene in a separate window with its own swap chain and an associated device and context all owned by the plugin. I'm rendering the Unity scene to a texture and passing the native pointer of the texture to the plugin. Had Unity's texture been created with the `D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_SHARED` flag enabled, I could have simply accessed the texture using `OpenSharedResource` and created a `ID3D11ShaderResourceView` bound to it. But since Unity does not specify that flag at the creation of its texture, I need to copy that texture to another texture which is created with the `D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_SHARED` flag enabled. I'm facing issues while doing this copy.

---

To test this pipeline, I'm working with the [SpriteBatch](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Sprites-and-textures) example in [DirectXTK](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) tweaking it a little bit - create a texture using one device, and pass it on to another device (the original example uses the same device to create the first texture) which is responsible for rendering it on the screen.

I create a first texture from an image file using the first `ID3D11Device1` without the `D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_SHARED` flag enabled, and create a second empty texture using the second `ID3D11Device1` with the `D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_SHARED` flag enabled. Then I copy the contents of the first texture to the second texture, and create a `ID3D11ShaderResourceView` bound to the second texture.

```
ComPtr<ID3D11Resource> textureResource;
DX::ThrowIfFailed(CreateWICTextureFromFile(m_d3dDevice.Get(), L"cat.png", textureResource.GetAddressOf(), nullptr));

ComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> cat;
DX::ThrowIfFailed(textureResource.As(&cat));

CD3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC catDesc;
cat->GetDesc(&catDesc);

ComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> spriteBatchTexture;
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC sharedTextureDesc = catDesc;
sharedTextureDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
sharedTextureDesc.Format = catDesc.Format;
sharedTextureDesc.MiscFlags = D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_SHARED;
sharedTextureDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;

//Create a texture which is a copy of cat, that belongs to the wicDevice but with a SHARED flag
DX::ThrowIfFailed(wicDevice->CreateTexture2D(&sharedTextureDesc, nullptr, spriteBatchTexture.ReleaseAndGetAddressOf()));
wicContext->CopyResource(spriteBatchTexture.Get(), cat.Get());

IDXGIResource* sharedResource(nullptr);
HANDLE sharedHandle;
DX::ThrowIfFailed(spriteBatchTexture->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIResource), (void**)&sharedResource));
DX::ThrowIfFailed(sharedResource->GetSharedHandle(&sharedHandle));
sharedResource->Release();
DX::ThrowIfFailed(m_d3dDevice->OpenSharedResource(sharedHandle, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (void**)(spriteBatchTexture.GetAddressOf())));

D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC sbSRVDesc = {};
sbSRVDesc.Format = catDesc.Format;
sbSRVDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
sbSRVDesc.Texture2D.MipLevels = 1;
sbSRVDesc.Texture2D.MostDetailedMip = 0;

DX::ThrowIfFailed(m_d3dDevice->CreateShaderResourceView(spriteBatchTexture.Get(), &sbSRVDesc, m_texture.ReleaseAndGetAddressOf()));
```

The `m_texture` is the `ID3D11ShaderResourceView` that is finally used by the example to render the image on to the screen.

The code goes through fine, but there's no image rendered onto the window when I do this.

*Note*: It does not seem to matter which device - `m_d3dDevice` or `wicDevice` I choose as the creator of the `spriteBatchTexture`. As long as `OpenSharedResource` is used properly, the code does not break but the end result is the same blank screen.

Comment: Turn on the debug device and look for output messages. You'll note that ``CopyResource`` doesn't return success or failure, so if it fails it does so silently.